# Bivariate normal cdf concave in correlation?

Tags: normal-distribution

Is there such a result that the bivariate normal distribution function is a concave function in rho? In my simulations it looks like it, but I need a analytical proof. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: The bivariate normal function looks concave for equal upper bounds according to the code:library(mvtnorm)
corr=function(r) matrix(c(1,r,r,1),nrow=2)
t1e= function(r)
{
  1-pmvnorm(upper=c(1,0.9),corr=corr(r))[1]
}

rvec<-seq(-1,1,0.1)

as=sapply(rvec,FUN="t1e")

plot(rvec,as, xlab=expression(rho), ylab="cdf", type="l")

Comment: I tried calculating the second derivative by exchanging integration and differentiation, but could not show that the result is greater than zero.